# Updating specific columns within the table of unsequential/skipping Id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update

I have a table with ~4k rows that need their data only in specific columns.

In other words UPDATE of only the specific columns within all the rows while in the same time not touching the data of existing columns - with nonsequential Id's e.g. (1,2,3,4,7,8,9,11 etc.).

So this query that I've written fails:

```
  UPDATE dbo.SURFACE2
  SET Xwgs = dt.Xwgs, Ywgs = dt.Ywgs
  FROM 
     (
        SELECT
            Id as InId,
            Xwgs,
            Ywgs
        FROM dbo.SURFACE2
        WHERE 
            Id BETWEEN 3693 AND 7369
     ) dt
  WHERE
    Id = dt.InId - 3692
```

Since Id's are nonsequential not all the rows are filled and many are filled erroneously(in an expected destination row I have data for the earlier one source row).

What would be a better way of accomplishing this without having to recreate this into a new table with sorted Id's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query was straight; turns out I needed respective Id's for what I've imported from the
excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, but it can be simplified to:

```
UPDATE s
  SET Xwgs = dt.Xwgs,
        Ywgs = dt.Ywgs
  FROM dbo.SURFACE2 s JOIN
       dbo.SURFACE2 ss
       ON s.Id = ss.InId - 3692
  WHERE ss.Id BETWEEN 3693 AND 7369;
```

Comment: My 'bulb' flickered  - will try something - thanks for the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `row_number()` to renumber the rows first, then apply the logic:

```
with cte as (select s.*, row_number() over(order by id) rn from surface2)
update t
set t.Xwgs = s.Xwgs, t.Ywgs = s.Ywgs
from cte t
inner join cte s on s.rn = t.rn - 3692
where t.rn between 3693 and 7369
```